# Запрос из Базы Данных MSSQL 2008

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, запрос

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу процедуру в MS SQL 2008 R2.
Добился создания таблицы (ниже)

```
Таблица_1

ID     Имя_Проекта    Этап         Сдал    Всего_Этапов
1       ДОМ          Проект        True         4
2       ДОМ        Пристройка      True         4
3       ДОМ          Кухня         True         4
4       ДОМ          Туалет        False        4
5       ДАЧА          Проект1      True         3
6       ДАЧА        Пристройка1    True         3
7       ДАЧА          Кухня1       True         3
```

Там много таких записей, но суть в том что нужно получить из нее другую таблицу вида:

```
Таблица_2

ID     Имя_Проекта    Сдал    Всего_Этапов
1          ДОМ         3            4
2          ДАЧА        3            3
```

Уже и COUNT перепробовал и много другое, но уже вошел в отчаяние, не особо силен в SQL

Comment: Что значит столбец `Всего_Этапов`? И что из этого стобца должно попасть в итоговую выборку?

Comment: В Первой таблице проект ДОМ состоит из 4 этапов (Проект, Пристройка, Кухня, Туалет), 3 из них (Проект, Пристройка, Кухня)  завершены а один (Туалет) нет.
В проекте ДАЧА 3 этапа (Проект1, Пристройка1,Кухня1) и завершены все 3.

В итоговую таблицу должно попасть Имя проекта и сколько этапов завершено из Всего кол-ва этапов для этого Проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если поле [Сдал] в таблице имеет тип bit:

```
select 
     MIN(ID) as ID, 
     [Имя_Проекта], 
     SUM(CASE WHEN [Сдал] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Сдал],
     [Всего_Этапов]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Имя_Проекта], [Всего_Этапов]
```

Comment: Тип данных операнда bit недопустим для оператора sum.

Comment: Лучше тогда сделать с условием `select 
     MIN(ID) as ID, 
     [Имя_Проекта], 
     COUNT(*) as [Сдал],
     [Всего_Этапов]
FROM MyTable WHERE [Сдал] = 1
GROUP BY [Имя_Проекта], [Всего_Этапов]`